# How to convert LDAP timestamp to Unix timestamp

Tags: php, ldap, timestamp

When I retrieve the LDAP attribute "pwdLastSet" of an Active Directory using PHP I get a value like 1.29265206716E+17. I know that this value represents the date "Tue Aug 17 2010 14:11:11 GMT+0200".

How can I convert this value to a Unix timestamp in PHP? Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ldap-get-entries.php#33180).

Actually it boils down to converting the `FILETIME` timestamp into a UNIX timestamp:

```
$fileTime = "130435290000000000";
$winSecs       = (int)($fileTime / 10000000); // divide by 10 000 000 to get seconds
$unixTimestamp = ($winSecs - 11644473600); // 1.1.1600 -> 1.1.1970 difference in seconds
echo date(DateTime::RFC822, $unixTimestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks! Here's the same one in Java: Date d = new Date((long) (timestamp / 10000) - 11644473600000);

Answer (score 3):

Rather than ask the same question for another language.

*Python 3:*

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def ldap2datetime(ts: float):
    return datetime(1601, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=ts/10000000)

print(ldap2datetime(132255350424395239).isoformat())
# 2020-02-07T07:44:02.439524
```

Comment: note that this gives naive datetime, which defaults to *local time* in Python - while the epoch here should be UTC

Answer (score 2):

There's [this page](http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-2000-active-directory/2286/Format-of-pwdLastSet-in-Active-Directory) suggesting that it is "100-nanosecond units passed since 1.1.1601 00:00:00", this might be helpful.

EDIT: 1600 »» 1601

Comment: Don't know why someone down-voted this one... Shouldn't be too hard to convert this answer into PHP code. You shouldn't always expect ready-to-use code...

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateLargeInt= "1.29265206716E+17"; // nano seconds since jan 1st 1601
$secsAfterADEpoch = $dateLargeInt / (10000000); // seconds since jan 1st 1601
$ADToUnixConvertor=((1970-1601) * 365.242190) * 86400; // unix epoch - AD epoch * number of tropical days * seconds in a day
$unixTsLastLogon=intval($secsAfterADEpoch-$ADToUnixConvertor); // unix Timestamp version of AD timestamp
$lastlogon=date("d-m-Y", $unixTsLastLogon); // formatted date
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php for details

Answer (score 1):

@etranger - correction: should be timestamp from 1601 instead of 1600.
Refer to offical microsoft website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Node.JS/Browser JS:

```js
const convertInt64Timestamp = timestamp => {
   const offsetInMs = Number.parseInt(timestamp) / 10_000;
   const baseDate = Date.parse('1601-01-01T00:00:00Z');
   return new Date(baseDate + offsetInMs);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

bash

If the string contains 18 or more digits, this number will be converted to a date in the format +%D_%T. If there are more than 18 digits, the conversion will be incorrect. If the string does not contain 18 or more digits, it is displayed in its original form.

```
$ echo 'something before 132539220002262206 something later' | sed -r 's/(.*)([0-9]{18})(.*$)/echo "\1""$(date +%D_%T -d \@$(((\2\/10000000)-11644473600)))""\3"/e'

$ ldapsearch=(
'dn: CN=John Doe,OU=Neverland,OU=Non-existent,DC=example,DC=com'
'whenCreated: 20210101000000.0Z'
'lastLogon: 132539220002262206'
'pwdLastSet: 132539220003262206'
'sAMAccountName: j.doe'
'userPrincipalName: j.doe@example.com')

$ printf "%s\n" "${ldapsearch[@]}" 
dn: CN=John Doe,OU=Neverland,OU=Non-existent,DC=example,DC=com
whenCreated: 20210101000000.0Z
lastLogon: 132539220002262206
pwdLastSet: 132539220003262206
sAMAccountName: j.doe
userPrincipalName: j.doe@example.com

$ printf "%s\n" "${ldapsearch[@]}" | sed -r 's/(.*)([0-9]{18})(.*$)/echo "\1""$(date +%D_%T -d \@$(((\2\/10000000)-11644473600)))""\3"/e' 
dn: CN=John Doe,OU=Neverland,OU=Non-existent,DC=example,DC=com
whenCreated: 20210101000000.0Z
lastLogon: 01/01/21_00:00:00
pwdLastSet: 01/01/21_00:00:00
sAMAccountName: j.doe
userPrincipalName: j.doe@example.com
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The current timezone in LDAP is 0. If you want to increase or decrease the timezone, you need to follow the formula 60 seconds multiply 60 minutes multiplied by X hours (60 * 60 * X) = Y will get the number of seconds. X is the timezone you want to increase or decrease. If you want to increase the timezone, use ($ ADToUnixConverter += Y) otherwise use ($ ADToUnixConverter -= Y).

```
$time = '132608472643065510'; //nano seconds since jan 1st 1601
$secsAfterADEpoch = $ldapTime / 10000000; //seconds since jan 1st 1601
$ADToUnixConverter = ((1970 - 1601) * 365 - 3 + round((1970 - 1601) / 4)) * 86400; //unix epoch - AD epoch * number of tropical days * seconds in a day
$ADToUnixConverter += 25200; // (+7 hours) 
$lastLogonTimesamp= ($secsAfterADEpoch - $ADToUnixConverter);
echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $lastLogonTimesamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP solution**

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67992361/1936720, it can be done in PHP using

```php
$time = '133220124000000000';
$date = new DateTime('1601-01-01', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->modify('+' . ($time / 10000000) . ' seconds');
```