# Unix timestamp to LDAP timestamp

Tags: php, windows, unix, time, ldap

There's a lot of examples on how to convert LDAP->Unix, but I can't for the love of god convert it back as in Unix->LDAP..

Here's what i've got for LDAP->Unix:

[How to convert LDAP timestamp to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647169/how-to-convert-ldap-timestamp-to-unix-timestamp)
http://www.morecavalier.com/index.php?whom=Apps%2FLDAP+timestamp+converter

```
function LDAPtoUnix($t) {
    $secsAfterADepoch = $t / (100000000);
    $AD2Unix = ( (1970-1601) * 365 -3 + round((1970-1601)/4) ) * 86400;
    return intval($secsAfterADepoch-$AD2Unix);
}
```

Which i think should be accurate.
But I'm twisting my puny little brain to reverse the mathematics and i can't figure out it..
My head is boiling to just calculate the difference in seconds between the different epochs and simple adding/subtracting them to given time parameter?

Can someone shed some light on how to reverse the timestamp?

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679430(v=vs.85).aspx

Also the main reason for why I'm asking besides my brain not wanting to compute that mathematics is that the floating point mechanism of PHP appears to be not so specific as it needs to be?
If i calculate Unix->LDAP timestamp, i'll end up with `1.3009518089E+17` and i'm not sure that Active Directory likes this particular notaion, so i would need to store it in a string but i can't figure out how to calculate these large numbers and not end up with a double.

At the moment i've got:

```
printf("%.0f", UnixToLDAP(time()));
```

which gives me the correct length but it's not really specific.

## What i need

Short and simple,
Unix->LDAP timestamp that fits in `pwdLastSet` in Active Directory.
Also, it must be as perfect as possible, my attempts doesn't end well when checking: http://www.morecavalier.com/index.php?whom=Apps%2FLDAP+timestamp+converter

## Google: Automatic solution (Windows 2012 Active Directory)

You can simply state -1 in pwdLastSet and Windows will automaticly set the time to the last login after the password was changed. It's not perfect but it works for anyone googling and ending up here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your function a bit more readable by naming the input parameter properly and assigning an intermediate variable before returning. Since `$AD2Unix` is actually a fixed term, it could probably be a constant; for now, I've just moved it to the top of the function:

```
function LDAPtoUnix($ldap_ts) {
    $AD2Unix = ( (1970-1601) * 365 -3 + round((1970-1601)/4) ) * 86400;

    $secsAfterADepoch = $ldap_ts / 100000000;
    $unix_ts = intval( $secsAfterADepoch - $AD2Unix );

    return $unix_ts;
}
```

We now have 2 lines to invert; they clearly need to happen in reverse order, and then using simple algebra to rearrange the terms in each (`/` becomes `*`, `-` becomes `+`) we get this:

```
function UnixtoLDAP($unix_ts) {
    $AD2Unix = ( (1970-1601) * 365 -3 + round((1970-1601)/4) ) * 86400;

    $secsAfterADepoch = intval( $AD2Unix + $unix_ts );
    $ldap_ts = $secsAfterADepoch * 100000000;

    return $ldap_ts;
}
```

A couple of tests suggest this inverts the original nicely.

Comment: Yepp, my syntax is quite off on this one.
I've been lazy and just writing as-found from the internet because the development laptop is isolated from the world (no internet, usb etc) and i've got another computer with google results, so i'm typing "sideways" and it's easier to just copy paste the whole shabang and fixing it later :) thx for the notice tho :) Your solution works!

Comment: Well, I coded all this "blind" before pasting into an environment where I could test it; the tidying was just so I could see how the maths worked. Oddly, I seem to get one too many zeroes according to the JS solution you linked to, but I can't see why.

Comment: Odd, your solution fixes the floatingpoint issue tho of PHP which is neet! :)

Comment: NB : I've tried this solution, it works but if its a leap year you need to add 86400  to `$AD2Unix` var.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `intval()`, it will overflow on 32-bit PHP, just let PHP use float.

```php
function toLdap($unixTimeStamp) {
    return ($unixTimeStamp + 11644473600) * 10000000;
}

function toUnix($ldapTimeStamp) {
    return (int) (($ldapTimeStamp / 10000000) - 11644473600);
}
```

And you can calculate the diff of Unix and LDAP time using `DateTime` (more readable)

```php
$diff = (new DateTime('1970-01-01'))
     ->diff(new DateTime('1601-01-01'))
     ->days * (24 * 60 * 60);

echo $diff; // 11644473600
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function UnixToLDAP($t) {
    $AD2Unix = ( (1970-1601) * 365 -3 + round((1970-1601)/4) ) * 86400;
    return intval($t+$AD2Unix) * 100000000;
}
```

Comment: And your solution works too, Any way to not ruin the floatingpoint details that PHP f*** up completely with large numbers? :)

Comment: Not using intval() was the solution to the later