# php ldap timestamp converter

Tags: php, ldap

Iam trying to convert ldap timestamp to date format. Below is the code iam using, but the output not getting exactly.

**Here is the code:**

```
$time = strtotime('20150709142652Z');  
echo date('d M, Y H:m:s A T',$time);
```

My output: `09 Jul, 2015 19:07:52 PM IST`

I am comparing my output with this site: `http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/ldap-timestamp.php`

Please tell me what to change in my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert LDAP timestamp to Unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647169/how-to-convert-ldap-timestamp-to-unix-timestamp)

Comment: please anyone reply for this.

Answer (score 0):

actually your code and output is correct

this converter (https://www.epochconverter.com/ldap) using local timestamp. please check GMT or local time zone to compare your result.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647169/how-to-convert-ldap-timestamp-to-unix-timestamp) with this code

```
$fileTime = "20150709142652Z";
$winSecs       = (int)($fileTime / 10000000); // divide by 10 000 000 to get seconds
$unixTimestamp = ($winSecs - 11644473600); // 1.1.1600 -> 1.1.1970 difference in seconds
echo date('d M, Y H:m:s A T',$unixTimestamp);
```

The "trick" is to convert it to unix timestamp first and then give the proper format.

Comment: Before providing an answer , please check the output from your end and then reply. Your above code doesnt work for me. BTW, I have given $fileTime = "20150709142652Z"

Comment: Well I am not going to code for you, I just provided an answer from another question that does the same you are asking.

Comment: I would suggest you to change the number from your code to mine ;)

Comment: i adapted it for you ;)