# Convert timestamp from MS AD in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, timestamp

i have 18 digit timestamps from AD like this 131963400057892956
i want convert to any human readable in Linux..

i tried something this

`echo '131963400057892956/864000000000-109207' | bc |xargs -I DATE date -d @DATE`

i get Thu Jan  1 17:05:28 +05 1970

but it's wrong way.. how make it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with awk, processing the string with the required calculations taken from [How to convert LDAP timestamp to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647169/how-to-convert-ldap-timestamp-to-unix-timestamp) and running it through awk's strftime function to get the locale date:

```
awk '{dat=($0/10000000)-11644473600;print strftime("%c",dat) }' <<< "131963400057892956"

Wed 06 Mar 2019 10:00:05 GMT
```

Change %c as required.

Comment: https://www.epochconverter.com/ldap get Epoch/Unix time: 1551866405
GMT: Wednesday, 6 March 2019 г., 10:00:05

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer.